# Mapping jOOQ join result into multiple POJOs

Tags: kotlin, jooq

Say you have a query with multiple joins:

```
    db.select()
        .from(A)
        .join(B).onKey()
        .join(C).onKey()
        .fetch()
```

How can I fetch this into a `Map<A_POJO, List<Map<B_POJO, List<Map<C_POJO, List<D_POJO>>>>`?

I know there is `fetchGroup`, but I'm not sure it works for more than one join?

Comment: This sounds like a job for a nice `Stream` and `Collector` pipeline. Have you tried that?

Comment: @LukasEder bizarrely I was thinking about this issue last night and wondered what your opinion would be (we chatted at a London conference). When binning JPA, renormalisation is painful. The best I've come up with is an `equals` method on each table class that only compares `id` and as you suggest, a bit of Java 8 Streams action. It feels dirty / boilerplate and the unit tests are dirt-nasty long, especially if there are several joins. How was Abraham Lincoln doing it, back in the day?

Comment: @RobertBain: Thanks for your message. I think it's quite impossible to answer here through Stack Overflow comments without going back and forth in a lengthy discussion. Would you mind asking your question on the mailing list, with some details? https://groups.google.com/d/forum/jooq-user